# Is it possible to get the DocString of a typed class property in Python 3?

Tags: python, annotations, docstring

I'm messing with the `typing` module in Python 3 to see how far I can stretch it for a DSL. In order to make this DSL usable, I'd like to extract the DocStrings of some user-defined classes, like this one:

```py
class MyRecord:
    """
    This is just a foo.

    Wouldn't it be cool if you could extract this DocString's text at runtime?
    """
    foo: str
```

I've been searching and found [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) but it does not tell me anything about the use of DocStrings for this case. The only information I could find is on how to embed type information within a DocString, but that is not what I'm after.

FWIW, Python does not complain when feeding it the above example. However, it also does not seem to populate a `__doc__` attribute, either. Am I correct in assuming this is currently not part of the standard and as such not supported?

**Update:** I have done a terrible job at explaining what I'm trying to achieve. I've posted an answer that contains a much better example:

```py
class MyRecord:
    foo: str
    """
    This is a foo.
    """
    bar: str
    """
    This is a bar.
    """
```

As is to be expected, there is no way to access this data in the current specification. The only solution is to parse the AST and extract it from there using e.g. `inspect.getsource()`.

Comment: Docstrings are free text. There is no special syntax or format to them. On the other hand there are some conventions defined by third party tools (Sphinx, Epydoc,…) . Also docstrings are unrelated to type annotations. And you extract them simply with `MyRecord.__doc__`.

Comment: Hi Klaus, `MyRecord.__doc__` is empty in the above example; that's where I'm stuck. You're right about the format, of course.

Comment: Oh, it gets more interesting ... Seems like it has something to do with the fact I call `exec()`. Will update the question once I've figured out what's happening.

Comment: Ok, never mind, I've just discovered that it is populated when I **don't** use `exec()`, and that the resulting `__doc__` is pretty useless. Time to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docstrings can be extracted from any python object either with the `help(obj)` built-in, using `inspect.get_doc(obj)` or `obj.__doc__`.

```py
import inspect

class MyRecord:
    """
    This is just a foo.

    Wouldn't it be cool if you could extract this DocString's text at runtime?
    """
    foo: str

>>> inspect.getdoc(MyRecord)
"This is just a foo.\n\nWouldn't it be cool if you could extract this DocString's text at runtime?"
```

The type hint can be read at runtime using the typing module:

```py
(import typing)
>>> typing.get_type_hints(MyRecord)
{'foo': str}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for providing an example. It made me realize that I was using the **class** DocString and in no way was assigning the DocString to the properties. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was being incredibly stupid. Of course, the first DocString in the example is the **class DocString**, and is never associated with a method/property.

This would have been a better example:

```py
class MyRecord:
    foo: str
    """
    This is a foo.
    """
    bar: str
    """
    This is a bar.
    """
```

But unfortunately this is not accessible in the current CPython implementation, and I am not sure it ever will.